# Calling asp.net mvc controller's from normal aspx web form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i want to make some question about asp.net mvc.
How i call asp.net mvc controller action from normal aspx web form?
Our project is used asp.net mvc framework with visual studio 2008 C#.net.
For eg,i want to use like this in normal aspx web form.

```
public ActionResult callMvc()
{
    return RedirectToAction("Display","TempController");
}
```

I know it should not using like this way in MVC project,but,we need for some case.

Regards

Indi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use a Response.Redirect with the right url which get routed to your controller in question, I guess in your case, that is:

```
Response.Redirect("/Temp/Display");
```

Comment: thanks for your answer my fri,Before i call that action,url is like this "http://localhost:50834/Normal/WebForm.aspx"
it's in normal aspx web form,And then,i call action like yours way.
it shows error "The resource cannot be found".url becomes like this
"http://localhost:50834/Normal/Temp/Display"
Actually,this controller url is "http://localhost:50834/Temp/Display"
How i solve?

regards
Indi

Comment: @Indi: try Response.Redirect("../Temp/Display");

Answer (score 1):

It would be a better idea to use the Url helper to resolve the url for you, that way if your routes change then you don't have to refactor your code. Use this method;

```
Response.Redirect(Url.Action("Display", "Temp"));
```

I have never used it in this context before but I believe it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

`Response.Redirect("~/Home/Index");`

`Controller/action`

Comment: Can you expand on your answer?

Answer (score 0):

In WebForm cs file (class derived from System.Web.UI.Page) use:

```
this.Response.RedirectToRoute(new { controller="ControllerToRedirectTo", action="ActionToRedirectTo", id=5, SomeOtherActionParameter="Parameter value" });
```