# Can i use "@Url.Action" in c# (Inside .aspx page)

Tags: c#, url.action

Hi i am trying to add "@Url.Action" in c#.net (WebForms) to resolve the path conflict in server and with my local system using configuration file. 
i had this line and in this i am trying to use url.action in href property.

```
<a href="/User/Add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>&nbsp;Add User</a>
```

my question is how to use this url.action method .......

i tried like

> `href="@Url.Action("Add","User")"`

but its not accepting this....
thank you..

Comment: <a href="@Url.Action("Add", "User")"></a> seems okay for Razor syntax, what do you mean by "not accepting"?

Comment: @htiru Ignore the Error and try to run/build your project.

Comment: what error do you get ? do you try it?

Comment: the error is ** 404 ** and the url is **   http://localhost:7469/Home/@Url.Action(%22Add%22,%20%22User%22) **

Comment: Like Ian said, what do you mean by "not accepting" ? Because C#.Net doesn't provide this extension of code alone. The Razor Engine must be used with. Do you have the right packages included in your project ?

Comment: so do i need to install RazorEngine from nuget manager ?? @D4rkTiger

Comment: Yes absolutly, if you don't have the Razor Mvc packages to solve Razor extensions Visual Studio couldn't solve references ;-)

Comment: i have added the razorengine nuget to my packages and now can i use the same syntax like href='@Url.Action('Add','User)''.. or need any other syntax..

Comment: Make sure you have an action Add() inside UserController, and you have created a view with name add or you must have any other view which is being return by Add() action.

Comment: its not mvc i am doing in instead c#@Pawan

Comment: Sorry, I was not aware of this.

Comment: Normally you can use it like you have written @htiru

Comment: guys, read the question, this guys does not use .NET MVC, he does use .NET WebForms. Adding Razor is just one part of the problem.

Comment: @htiru, please see my answer and mark it as correct if you think it answered your question. by doing so you help the future visitors of stackoverflow checking your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I am aware, `Url.Action` is intended only for .NET MVC, not for .NET WebForms - there are no actions and no controllers in the WebForms.

Moreover, from your comments it seems like the terms C# and MVC should be clarified. C# is a programming language. You can use C# with both frameworks .NET MVC and .NET WebForms. You can use C# in both the .cshtml files (thanks to Razor view engine) and the ASPX pages.

Answer (score 3):

use the following:

```
<%=new System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper(this.Request.RequestContext).Action("Index", "DetailedConferenceReport") %>
```

Or

Just use this

```
<a class="btn btn-warning " href="../DetailedConferenceReport/Index">                                    
    <i class="fa fa-backward"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This think works for me, I used a link this way

```
<a href="@Url.Action("LogOut", "Account")">hi </a>
```

And this is working for me. Can you copy the html from source of the page and verify?

Comment: this might works in mvc(cshtml) but what about in c#(.aspx)

Comment: I don't think you can do it in a WebForms project. The '@Url.Action()' method is for MVC only. The parameters are Controller and Action. You have to do it as you mentioned in the question.This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931869/calling-asp-net-mvc-controllers-from-normal-aspx-web-form) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have a problem with the " quotes try using
    `<a href='@Url.Action("Add", "User")'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>&nbsp;Add User</a>`

Comment: still doesn't work @daveHutchy. i am trying this in c#(.aspx)

Comment: Ah right, then i believe as @Anton has mentioned that in .aspx (Web Forms) that is not available and will only work for .NET MVC projects. However i am pretty sure that you could use a Jquery Ajax call to this Method depending on the context you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you just have to add

*Microsoft.AspNet.Razor*

which by dependency includes all others it needs

Answer (score 0):

We can use ResolveUrl instead .. That's work fine in c#

Answer (score 0):

U can use `<%=Url.Action("index", "Home")%>` in Asp.net Webform
and  `@Url.Action("index", "Home")` in Asp.net MVC

Answer (score -1):

Because it seems you're using .aspx and not .cshtml ("Razor"), you'd need to use

```
<a href="<%= Url.Action("Add","User") %>"> ... </a>
```

Note: This is for an MVC application

You can check [ASP.NET "special" tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags) for a quick run-down for the .aspx tags, and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fy30at8h(v=vs.100).aspx for full MSDN documentation on .aspx syntax.

Comment: had an error **The name 'Url' does not exist in the current context** @nullReference

Comment: Sorry then - Url.Action is meant for MVC applications, it won't work in a WebForms application